# Sapreste dirmi qual è la distribuzione geografica dei termini 'fioraio', 'fiorista' e 'fioreria'?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Sapreste dirmi qual è la distribuzione geografica dei termini "fioraio", "fiorista" e "fioreria"?
Come noto, i termini si riferiscono alle attività di vendita dei fiori.

Sapreste dirmi, al di là degli usi locali, quale sarebbe il più appropriato termine?

Answer (score 2):

The traditional distinction is that *il **fioraio** vende fiori freschi, il **fiorista** fabbrica e vende fiori artificiali* (Eugenio Treves, *...Si dice?...*, Ceschina 1961, and some dictionaries). In practice, nowadays *fiorista* is felt as somewhat upper scale, as if a *fioraio* sold just any old flower while a *fiorista* sold elegant flower compositions.